# Analytic approximation of a series containing Bessel functions

Tags: power-series, bessel-functions

Because infinite series are expensive for numerical simulations, I am trying to approximate the following time and radius dependent function:

$$ 
    f(t,r)={\sum_{n=1}^\infty}{{J_0(r\cdot a_n)}\over {{(a_n)^3e^{(a_n)^2t}J_1(a_n)}}}\tag1
$$

where:

- $ t$ is the dimensionless time
- $ r$ is the dimensionless radius
- $ J_0$ and $J_1$ are Bessel functions of the first kind of order zero and one.
- $ a_n$ is $n$-th zero of Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.

The boundaries are $t\in[0,t_{\text{finite}}] $ and $r\in[0,1] $.

I noticed a linear characteristic by plotting the function $a_n$. It appears that a good analytic expression of $a_n$ is
$$
a_n = \pi n-{\pi\over4}\tag2
$$

By using the above expression, I plotted equation $(1)$ for $n_{\max} =500$. A $2$D and $3$D plot is shown below.

Please tell me with what numerically cheap function can I approximate $f(t,r)$. The summation is probably too hard to solve considering it has two Bessel functions with different arguments.

Thank you for your time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use the fact that $J'_0=-J_1$ ?

Comment: To denote set inclusion, use $\in$ (`\in`), not $\epsilon$(`\epsilon`). They are different symbols.

Comment: Could you say the origin of this problem ?

Comment: Of course. The idea is to derive a mathematical expression for the fluid velocity that contains physically measurable parameters so it can be numerically simulated. The end goal is to use that simulation as an input to the simulation of a non-standard pneumatic actuator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite funny, I was running into exactly the same problem the other day.

---

I am assuming that the source of this sum is from [Batchelor's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Startup_of_Poiseuille_flow_in_a_pipe) to the time-varying flow of laminar pressure driven flow in a pipe. In dimensionless form, it can be expressed as

$$u(t,r)=2\left(1-r^2\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{16}{{s_n}^3}\frac{1}{J_1(s_n)}J_0\left(s_nr\right)\exp\left(-{s_n}^2~t\right)$$
The symbols used have the meanings

- $u=\frac{8\nu}{ga^2}u_{\text{real}}$ is the dimensionless velocity where $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity, $g$ is the kinematic pressure gradient, and $a$ is the radius of the pipe
- $J_\alpha$ is a Bessel function of the first kind
- $s_n$ is the $n$th positive real root of $J_0$
- $t=\frac{\nu t_{\text{real}}}{a^2}\in[0,\infty)$ is the dimensionless time
- $r=\frac{r_{\text{real}}}{a}\in[0,1]$ is the dimensionless radius

In fact asymptotic expressions for $s_n$ are [known](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82806344.pdf). In particular it is known that
$$s_n=-\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi+\frac{1}{8n\pi-\pi/4}+\mathrm O(n^{-3})\\ \text{as}~n\to\infty$$

We can combine this with known [asymptotic formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) for Bessel functions (given $x\in \Bbb R$):

$$J_1(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos\left(x-\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)+\mathrm O\left(|x|^{-3/2}\right) \\ \text{as}~|x|\to\infty$$

Which means,

$$J_1(s_n)\asymp \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}~\frac{4\pi(32n-1)}{16+\pi^2-36\pi^2 n+128\pi^2n^2}\cos\left(\frac{4+\pi^2-33\pi^2 n+32\pi^2n^2}{\pi(32n-1)}\right) \\ \text{as}~n\to\infty$$

A crude, but nonetheless [very good](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ncgfpvmavi) approximation of this is

$$J_1(s_n)\approx 2^{1/2}\pi^{-3/2}\frac{1}{9/32-n}\cos(\pi n)\sim -2^{1/2}\pi^{-3/2}\frac{1}{n}$$

Also, from our asymptotic expansion for $s_n$, we can deduce
$$\frac{1}{{s_n}^3}\approx\frac{1}{\pi^3}\frac{1}{\big(n-1/4\big)^3}\sim\frac{1}{\pi^3n^3}$$

Putting these together, this means that
$$\boxed{\left|\frac{1}{{s_n}^3}\frac{1}{J_1(s_n)}\right|\sim2^{-1/2}\pi^{-3/2}n^{-2}} $$
([check](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pjwprxuygq) for yourself)

Finally, we approximate the exponential bit. By the same reasoning as before, we have
$${s_n}^2\approx \pi^2 \big(n-1/4\big)^2$$
So
$$\exp(-{s_n}^2 t)\sim \frac{1}{e^{\pi^2n^2 t}}$$

So in all we have the **very** crude but nonetheless enlightening approximation

$$\boxed{\left|\frac{16}{{s_n}^3}\frac{1}{J_1(s_n)}\exp(-{s_n}^2 t)\right|\sim 16\cdot 2^{-1/2}\pi^{-3/2}\frac{1}{n^2e^{\pi^2n^2 t}}}$$

Note that this expression shrinks w.r.t $n$ **very fast**, and does so even faster as $t$ increases.

Keeping in mind that the maximum value that $u$ takes in the channel is $2$, once the terms in the sum become smaller than, say $\frac{2}{1000}$, they are probably ok to neglect. As far as I can tell from my numerical investigation, for all $t>0.01$, this happens in the worst case after $6$ terms. So, all together, my suggestion to you is to use the expression

$$\boxed{\small{u(t,r)\approx 2(1-r^2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{6}{t+1}\right\rceil}\frac{16}{\sqrt{2\pi^3}}\frac{\frac{9}{32}-n}{\big(n-1/4\big)^3}~\sec(\pi n)~J_0\left(\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}+n\pi\right)r\right)\exp\left(-\pi^2\big(n-1/4\big)^2 t\right)}}$$

And hopefully you should have pretty good results :)

---

### **EDIT:**

As an example, the exact expression for $u(t,r)$ gives the velocity after half a second at the center of the pipe as $u(0.5,0)=1.82032$ whereas the approximate expression gives $u(0.5,0)\approx 1.78435$. Not bad. The Mathematica code is shown below:

[image: mathematica code]

Comment: Minor comment: when approximating $J_1(s_n)$, $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$ and not $1$. Of course you will take absolute values so this won't cause any problem.

Comment: @Gary I know. I just wanted to take about the relative size of the terms

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much @K.defaoite. And also, you are right. This is for pipe flow simulations :D